# Child opacity affecting parent

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.  I looked through the related posts and couldn't find anything similar to what I'm dealing with.

I have an image that when hovered on, the opacity reduces.  I have text in a DIV above the DIV containing the image, which is affected by the opacity setting of the image.  The text is suppose to stay solid, while the image becomes transparent.  Unfortunately, both elements are becoming transparent on hover.  I thought that since the text is considered a parent element, it should not be affected by the opacity setting of the image.

html:

```
<div class="album large">
    <div class="writing">
        <h1>blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="opac">
        <img src="background/runaways.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.album img
    {
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    }

.album.large
    {
    background-image: url('background/bigblack.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }


.writing
    {
    position: absolute;
    color:red;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -270px;
    }

.opac img:hover
    {
    opacity: .4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    }
```

Comment: Can you set up a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: [Not for me](http://jsfiddle.net/XBmcr/). It works as expected.

Comment: Your code works perfectly alright. What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: safari.  The text isn't affected by the image opacity for you guys?

Comment: I tested it out in chrome and firefox and I'm still encountering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solve opacity issue of parent div**

Using Pseudo-elements we can get rid of this, Check the [link](http://sakhatech.com/blog/2013/07/24/pseudo-element-in-css3-and-html5/) given below for more details.